# div style background url issue with inspector

Tags: html, styles

I'm trying to follow along in this course I'm taking but when I changed my `img` tag to `<div style= "background:url/IMAGES/images.jpeg)"></div>` the inspector gives me an invalid property value icon in the element.style. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes i know div isn't self closing, i added the closing tag in html i just didn't type it in my question.

Comment: At first glance you just have invalid syntax; you're missing the opening parentheses, `background: url(/IMAGES/images.jpeg)` notice

Comment: I actually have the parentheses in my html i just missed it in post. i'll share exactly what it looks like.

Comment: <div style="background:url(/IMAGES/images.jpeg)" ></div>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just a small typo: you're missing the opening parenthesis. It should probably be something like this:

`style="background: url('/IMAGES/images.jpeg')"`

When using inline styles on your `div` look out for nested quotes as well.

Comment: This is how i wrote it in element.style to reflect my mentor's way. background: url (images.jpeg); and it says the property value is invalid but my mentor's doesn't say that.

Comment: CSS can be finicky. In your comment it looks like there's now a *different* syntax error: there should be no space between url and the opening parenthesis. You can see what's happening in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xkjpw29y/.